# How to check if a key exists in an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, literals

I have the following object literal:

```
{ 
  'key1': 
  { 
    id: 'rr323',
    d: undefined,
    x: 560,
    y: 150 
  },
  'key2': 
  { 
    id: 'rr231',
    d: undefined,
    x: 860,
    y: 90 
  } 
}
```

I want to implement an if statement such as below:

```
if(key DOES NOT exist in object){  
//perform certain function 
}
```

I tried the following:

```
var key = key1;
if(!(key in global_move_obj)){
 // function
}
```

But that always returns true value when it should return false.

Comment: `var key = key1` in your code should be `var key = 'key1'`, otherwise you're going to check if `undefined in global_move_obj`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) call:

```
if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
var key = 'key1';
if (!('key1' in obj)) {
    ....
} 
// or
if (!(key in obj)) {

}
```